# How can I save, reach and use a bitmap in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I create a bitmap by combining two images. I now try to store it, save it, see it and use it in the app.

This is how i create my new bitmap:

```
        string OnePath = "backgroundimage";
        string TwoPath = "objectimage";

        var OneImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resources.GetIdentifier(OnePath, "drawable", PackageName));
        var TwoImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resources.GetIdentifier(TwoPath, "mipmap", PackageName));

        Bitmap bitmap = OneImage.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Rect baseRect = new Rect(0, 0, OneImage.Width, OneImage.Height);
        Rect frontRect = new Rect(22, 31, 79, 79);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(TwoImage, frontRect, baseRect, null);
```

So I now look to save this new bitmap i created. What i've tried to do is the following:

```
        var documentsDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, OnePath);

        App.AppFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, OnePath);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(App.AppFileName);
```

Where `App.AppFileName` is a string storing the imagepath. I am now unsure if the created image actually gets saved there. If I open android file manager with a android phone connected to my computer, I do not see the image in the `App.AppFileName` path.

Comment: No other app can view data folder and open application data unless you give a root permission to it. Please check that or save your image on external storage.

Comment: @user2912553 how can i save it on external storage? I want to be able to see the image without creating an imageview in the app

Comment: Use Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDir. You should also ensure that your package has WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.